# route traffic directly without vpn while the vpn still connected

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, routing

I have a box with fedora, connected to vpn, forwarding done by iptables, every thing is fine, and it is always connected, vpn interface is ppp1, connected through the pppoe interface: ppp0, but sometimes I wont to get some traffic directly through ppp0 without vpn, with the vpn still connected, any idea?

Comment: Google split tunneling. What you're after is all standard VPN stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what VPN software you are using. This comes down to a routing issue.

Here's something to get you started from the Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control Howto:

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Under OpenVPN, you can do this on the client side or server side.

On the client:

```
redirect-gateway def1
allow-pull-fqdn
route www.google.be 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

See: https://forums.openvpn.net/topic8853.html

Comment: I am using NetworkManager to connect the pptp vpn.